# Using p-Channel MOSFET as a Switch to turn load on / off via BeagleBone Black GPIO

Tags: power, mosfet

Is this the correct way of using a pMOSFET as a High Side Switch?

I need a Load Device to be turned on/off (Vin Pin). The Load Device requires 5v 700mA power to run.

My logic is, when the beaglebone-black comes on, the GPIO is ON (3.3v High) by default, so the Load (Device) Gets 0v.

Once the board boots up, the startup Script turns the GPIO Pin low, which gives a high signal on the load side.

[image: Circuit Diagram Showing the Setup]

Comment: Your circuit is fine. But you may want to choose a Q4 to have lower Vgs. The current selection would be operating at the edge of its range. Lower Vgs or logic level MOSFETs are common anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a 1k Resistor between the Beaglebone GPIO pin and the Vgs of the BSS138. Works like a charm.